# How do I use a website quality checker if the website has a login page?

Tags: accessibility, section508, software-quality

I'm trying to test a website for 508 compliance, but it has a login page.

I've tried downloading pages of the whole website as an html file. But no site allows you to upload .html files, only links.

Comment: it's not obvious what your question is.  Are you trying to say that you want to test the site but can't because you don't have credentials?  that would be logical, you need credentials in order to access protected content.

Comment: or, reading this another way, you want to use a 3rd party website to check the first party website, but don't know how to give your credentials to the 3rd party? that wouldn't be advisable either.  If you are asking for a recommendation to a 3rd party that would work differently, this isn't the place for recommendations, due to the amount of spam they generate.

Comment: I'm trying to use 3rd party website to check a first party website. I do have the credentials (username and password). Lets say your signing into your gmail, you can't view the html & css of your inbox until you sign in.

Comment: right, so as I say, what is it you are trying to ask? this doesn't even appear to be a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install a plugin inside your favorite browser (see "chrome web store" or "add-ons for firefox" in google).

You have for instance a "wave toolbar"
http://wave.webaim.org/toolbar/

You can also install a bookmark let like a11.css https://ffoodd.github.io/a11y.css/